# WPF: does xml compile to bytecode?

Tags: xml, wpf, compilation

I am new to WPF, and here is my question: Does the XML part (the GUI design) compile to binary code during the compilation of the project? Or does it stay as XML, and being read EVERY time the application /window launches? If it starts as XML, then is it heavy for the performance, or it doesn't make a big difference?

Comment: It's actually XAML, and yes it compiles into the exe.  It does not stay as XAML.

Comment: @DJBurb so unlike JavaFX, it is being converted to C# code? Like JSP?

Comment: Don't know anything about JavaFX.  It doesn't convert into C# code.  I think it goes straight to binary code.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Adam Nathan, WPF Unleashed](http://www.adamnathan.net/wpf/), Part I.2. XAML Demystified.

Comment: It will be converted to something so called [BAML](http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/09/12/62-baml-is-compiled-xaml/)